# PHP: create gz stream from plain file

Tags: php, gzip, zlib, php-stream-wrappers

I want to create a read stream that previously is gzencoded from a plain text.

The google cloud storage library has an upload function and you can pass a StreamInterface as parameter ([Bucket::upload reference](https://cloud.google.com/php/docs/reference/cloud-storage/latest/Bucket#_Google_Cloud_Storage_Bucket__upload__))

I want to upload a .txt file but gzencoded.

To upload a txt file is simple:

```php
/** @var \Google\Cloud\Storage\Bucket $bucket */
$fd = fopen('/tmp/file.txt', 'r');
$stream = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Utils::streamFor($fd);
$bucket->upload($stream, ['name' => 'file.txt']);
```

I want to create a stream that:

- reads the original plain txt file
- does a gzencode in every chuck

And not storing the full file in memory (just the chunks) neither in disk. Is this possible?

I think it should be something like the following code, but creating a gz file (instead of zliz.deflating the data):

```php
$fd = fopen('/tmp/file.txt', 'r');
stream_filter_append($fd, 'zlib.deflate', STREAM_FILTER_READ, ['window' => 15]);
$stream = Psr7\Utils::streamFor($fd);
$bucket->upload($stream, ['name' => 'file.txt.gz']);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try using `zlib.deflate` stream filter with a different parameter set to produce a gzip-compatible output

Comment: While DEFLATE is the _algorithm_ used by gzip, it is not the _format_. This is laid out in the response to https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68556. This stream filter appears to use the DEFLATE _format_ header and trailer, and there does not currently seem to be a built-in gzip stream filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a bit nerd-sniped and had to write something for this.

Reposting my above comment:

> While DEFLATE is the algorithm used by gzip, it is not the format. This is laid out in the response to bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68556. This stream filter appears to use the DEFLATE format header and trailer, and there does not currently seem to be a built-in gzip stream filter.

Well we can shim in a call to the system's gzip *binary* with `proc_open()` and stream the data through that to create a properly-formatted gzip stream.

```php
class GzipCommandFilter extends php_user_filter {

    public $stream;
    private $ph, $pipes;

    public function onCreate(): bool {

        $this->ph = proc_open(
            [ 'gzip', '-c', '-'],
            [
                ['pipe', 'r'],
                ['pipe', 'w'],
                ['pipe', 'w']
            ],
            $this->pipes
        );

        if( $this->ph === false ) {
            return false;
        }

        stream_set_blocking($this->pipes[1], false);
        stream_set_blocking($this->pipes[2], false);

        return true;
    }

    public function filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing): int {
        $written = 0;

        while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in)) {
            fwrite($this->pipes[0], $bucket->data);
            $consumed += $bucket->datalen;

            $out_buf = stream_get_contents($this->pipes[1]);
            $written += strlen($out_buf);
            $bucket->data = $out_buf;
            stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
        }

        if( $closing ) {
            fclose($this->pipes[0]); // closing stdin to signal completion
            $this->waitOnProc(); // let gzip process the remaining buffer
            stream_bucket_append($out, stream_bucket_new($this->stream, stream_get_contents($this->pipes[1])));
            return PSFS_PASS_ON;
        } else if( $written > 0 ) {
            return PSFS_PASS_ON;
        } else {
            return PSFS_FEED_ME;
        }
    }

    protected function waitOnProc($step=1000, $max=1000000) {
        $waited = 0;
        while( ($status = proc_get_status($this->ph))['running'] === true ) {
            usleep($step);
            $waited += $step;
            if( $waited >= $max ) {
                throw new \Exception('Timed out while waiting.');
            }
        }
    }
}

stream_filter_register('gzip', 'GzipCommandFilter');
```

and we would use it like:

```php
$fh = fopen('/tmp/file.txt', 'rb');
stream_filter_append($fh, 'gzip');
$data = stream_get_contents($fh);
printf("Data: %s\nDecoded: %s\n", bin2hex($data), gzdecode($data));
```

Which might output something like:

```plain
Data: 1f8b0800000000000003cb48cdc9c95728cf2fca495104006dc2b4030c000000
Decoded: hello world!
```

Comment: ouh, nice, let me try this solution.

Comment: Shouldn't this work blocking? What is the requirement for non-blocking? Just asking, as I find this more and more often, but it never is explained in context.

Comment: @CAAHS IIRC If you leave it in blocking mode the read may block if there's no data in the stream and no EOF. Honestly the code plays a bit fast and loose with whether or not there's anything to pick up from gzip as there is no delay between writing to the input and reading the output in the main body of the filter as there's no way for the gzip binary to signal its internal state. Only at the end can we close STDIN and wait for the process to exit and know that we've got everything available.

Comment: Thinking about it more there's probably a way to do this entirely internal to PHP by wrapping a deflate stream filter and simply replacing the deflate header/trailer with that of gzip's. Going one step further to that, it's a bit puzzling that this isn't in PHP already.